# Get content between <p></p> tags in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I wanna read text between `<p></p>` tags which comes from database field. I think there may be html reader or something which I can assign the data including html tags retrieved from database to and use innerText(`<p>`) or something with I can get the text between `<p>` tags.

Is there any way to do something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the data html or **x**html? For xhtml, load it into `XmlDocument` (or `XDocument` etc) and access `InnerText` on the root element (or the element of choice). For (non-x)html, the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) serves a similar purpose, allowing xpath queries etc (`"//p"`, for example).

Comment: Marc, again you have the &nbsp; problem if you try and treat XHTML as XML

Comment: Thanks,that was beautiful answer. I don't know I could do something with XmlDocument onto xHTML.

Comment: Dan's warning should perhaps be heeded too... fortunately, Html agility pack has a **very** similar API to XmlDocument, so it wouldn't be hard to switch if you need.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst you could try a regular expression, the most robust way would be to use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to parse the coming text from the db or search inside for the tags you want, you can also use Regex.

I mean you will need to write the `innerText(<p>)` your self

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to XmlDocument and use Xpath to extract the content.

Comment: And if the HTML contains, say, "&nbsp;" it will break. That's why you use the HTML Agility Pack, as HTML != XML.